# ASP.net Login Control

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, login-control

This is a general question.  The login control from the Membership Provider asks for verification of the user's password but not of the email address.  To add verifaction of the email address, do I need to build a custom login control?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to validate the E-Mail address in addition to the username, yes you will need to build a custom validation control. You can then authenticate the user using your own function.

You can then handle the Authenticate event to run your own logic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The default membership provider uses the user's username and password to validate. For what you want to do, without extending the default provider and modifying the login control you could make the user's email their username, or you could alternatively add an email field to the login control and add an email verification after the Membership validation by using **GetUserNameByEmail** and setting **RequiresUniqueEmail** to **TRUE**.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to verify that the email does not exist then you can update you web.config membership section to state that emails need to be unique.

requiresUniqueEmail="false"